# how to add <hr> on wordpress blogs view section

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi guys i am new to WP development, this is my client site :  `bit.do/dFQtv` i need to add `hr` line under each blog excerpt below read more section , how to do it, if i insert the line below read more button that shows in the single blog post page also

this is coding: (template-parts/content.php)

```
 <?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 *
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_single() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"  rel="bookmark" >', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :  ?>
        <h4 class="meta text-muted">
            <?php blog_posted_on(); ?>
        </h4><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>

        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_mzc3" style="margin-bottom:20px;" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" </div>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">


        <?php
                     the_content( sprintf (
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
                wp_kses(__( 'Read more', 'blog' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => 
array() ) ) ),

                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
            ) );


               wp_link_pages( array(
                            'before' => '<div class= "page-links">'. esc_html__('Pages:', 'blog'
),

                           'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php blog_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

(template-parts/content-page.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying page content in page.php
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 *
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content"><hr>
        <?php
            the_content();


            wp_link_pages(array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__('Pages:','blog'),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->


    <?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php
                edit_post_link(
                    sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                        esc_html__( 'Edit %s', 'blog' ),
                        the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
                    ),
                    '<span class="edit-link">',
                    '</span>'
                );
            ?>
<hr>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: What you tried show the code

Comment: @Nawin <?php
                     the_content( sprintf (
    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
    wp_kses(__( 'Read more', 'bfablog' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => 
array() ) ) ),
<hr>
</div>

Comment: Try to edit your code to your question, not in the comment...

Comment: if i mention <hr> in (template-parts/content.php) its shows in the single post view

Comment: did you try in your `template-parts/archives.php`

Comment: You probably need to add it to `archive.php` or use CSS to add a `bottom-border`

Comment: @Nawin and @I haz kode  pls check the code now and the site link i have mentioned in the question

Comment: Try this and see if it works. `.blog .entry-content > p:last-of-type:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 0):

As per saw your theme you add your `<hr>` tag last line into your `content.php` inside the `template-parts`folder.
like this:

```
<footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php bfablog_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> --><hr>
```

Double check you edit the correct file...I tried and it's working

Comment: hi @Nawin its working but it also shows in the single post contents pages pls see this post url: bit.ly/2uHVIFN , 

I just want to show only in the blog archive page : bit.do/dFQtv

Comment: Thanks @Nawin i removed the hr from comment.php for single post , now its working fine i think, thanks again bro

Answer (score 0):

Just add hr tag after closing the article tag and also you can write CSS for it to change width and color of it.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying page content in page.php
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 *
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content"><hr>
        <?php
            the_content();


            wp_link_pages(array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__('Pages:','bfablog'),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->


    <?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php
                edit_post_link(
                    sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                        esc_html__( 'Edit %s', 'bfablog' ),
                        the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
                    ),
                    '<span class="edit-link">',
                    '</span>'
                );
            ?>
<hr>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
<hr class="abc" />
```